# Navbar fixed doesn't collapse when click on items (small screen device)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Im using bootstrap 4 and I have the solution to this with bootstrap 3 but appearently with bootsrap 4 is not quite the same. Im stuck and this is the  last thing in need in order to complete the project.
this is my navbar (with bootstrap 4):

```
 <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light pink" id="navbar-fixed">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/perfect-party-rental-logo.jpg" class="logo"></a>
        <!-- Collapse button -->
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupported" aria-controls="navbarSupported"
    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"></button>
<!-- Collapsible content -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupported">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" href="#home"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i> Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#inflatables"><i class="fa fa-smile-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Inflatables</a>
            </li>... <!--ETC-->
```

And this the JS code snipppet from bootstrap 3 :

```
            $(".navbar-collapse ul li a").click(function(event) {
      $(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide');
    });
```

The console keep saying "collapse" is not a function :S

Any clue?

Comment: Your code works exactly as expected; `.collapse` does not throw an error by default with your above code. Please update your question to include *all* of your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), including the references to both Bootstrap and jQuery as well.

Comment: Let me rephrase. I want to close my responsive menu get I click on an item inside the navbar and also when I click outside of the navbar. I want to automatically the resposive menu close up and be able to reopen it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of a working navbar in **Bootstrap 4** (as you can see it doesn't require any additional JavaScript snippets).

Click the "run code snippet" button and expand to full screen for testing:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

EDIT (adding from my comment):

I checked your codepen and while it was working on my side I saw this in the console: *"Uncaught Error: Bootstrap dropdown require Popper.js"* which means you aren't loading the popper.js which is required for all things that pop up or drop down in Bootstrap 4. Use the files I included at the bottom of my code snippet and it should work. Also, in your codepen you are loading bootstrap 4.0.0-beta.2. That version is **outdated** now. Copy and paste ALL stuff from my snippet. That's why I posted it for you.

Comment: I dont know why but on my home development enviroment doesnt work and I create this codepen with the exact same code and it work! But I dont... I will figure it out later here is the codepen with my code snippet  https://codepen.io/manAbl/pen/Jpjxeg

Comment: Just checked your codepen and while it was working on my side I saw this in the console: *"Uncaught Error: Bootstrap dropdown require Popper.js"* which means you aren't loading the popper.js which is required for all things that pop up or drop down in Bootstrap 4. Use the files I included at the bottom of my code snippet and it should work. Also, in your codepen you are loading bootstrap 4.0.0-beta.2. That version is **outdated** now. Copy and paste ALL stuff from my snippet. That's why I posted it for you.

Comment: Hey! I've found the answer to my issue, turns out I was loading jquery library twice so that was causing an error. Besides that your answer gived me the idea that maybe I was uploading some file the wrong way, 'cause I used an starter bootstrap template. Was really helpfull :)

Comment: Glad to hear that. Yes, in cases like these we need to check carefully what is it that's actually being loaded. I also happened to me in the past where I loaded the wrong stuff and was wondering why it's not working. Lesson learned! :-)